# so what is a db repository

Tags: linq-to-sql

So I am working on a project. Very small to learn ASP MVC 2.

Currently I am working on my computer and for my db I am using a sql server database file (mdf). When I host this online, the server will probably have sql server full version.

So my question is can I use LINQ to SQL ORM designer to design my database? Add my "properties" and such and it should automatically create the table in whatever database its connected too.

for example check the following picture. I want the test table to automatically make the table in whatever database I am using.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at ADO.NET Entity Framework 4 if you want to push your changes from your ORM to the database it is connected to.